Have I used ''spin your wheels'' correctly?

When learning a language, language learners often feel like they are spinning their wheels as progress is so gradual that many think they are stuck and aren't improving at all.

Is that a correct use of the expression spin one’s wheels?
I just feel like this idiom has niceties that I am unaware of and thus I might have used it incorrectly.

Do you mean learners feel that they "waste time doing things that achieve nothing"? or  feel they "use a lot of effort without achieving anything" ?

If the answer to @JamesK’s question is yes, then the answer to your question is yes.

... And found in the dictionary (Cambridge).  WHat I mean is that it is hard to check if something means what you want, unless we know what you want.

Yes, it's fine. Allow me to give you some useful advice. If you find something in a dictionary, like this expression, with examples and use it like those examples, why ask about it? Your level is already high enough to know whether you are using it correctly or not.

Hi! Please read about the topics covered here. To ask whether something is ok, please also tell why you think it might not be. In this case there's nothing wrong with the usage, but that's not much of an answer. Voting to close as lacking details until edited.

What I want to convey is that the learners feel like they don't see any results despite their efforts.

You used it perfectly from where I'm sitting. I knew what you meant as soon as I read it. One tip: Be consistent with your contractions: if you're going to use aren't, use they're: ...that many think they're stuck and aren't improving at all.
